# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.pandas_parser'

Tags: python, pandas

I installed python version python-3.10.8-amd64 . I then created a virtual environment named test_env. I afterwards installed Pandas. Everything went fine.

When I wanted to run this below script, it failed with this below error message:
The script content is:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```

```
(test_env) PS C:\Users\my_user\Documents> python .\pandas\my_test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\my_test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas\core\api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import (
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.pandas_parser  # noqa: E501 # isort: skip # type: ignore[reportUnusedImport]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.pandas_parser
```

I uninstalled python and installed it again.
I then successfully install pandas. I tried to execute the script again and it failed

Comment: It looks like you should use a different Pandas version or you have problems with the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the directories in the traceback,

> `C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas\__init__.py`

you have maybe copy-pasted the `pandas` module directory (partially?) from your virtualenv or somewhere into your working directory, and Python is trying to import from there.

Rename `C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas` to e.g. `C:\Users\my_user\Documents\pandas\pandas_foo`, and try again; it should then work.